# Move a project from one laptop with eclipse to another with android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, project

I have my project in eclipse on my old computer. I now have a new one I put android studio on.  Can anyone tell me how to get my project onto my new laptop with android studio from eclipse on my old computer?
My new computer has android studio not eclipse.

Comment: Export your projects as a zip file from old eclipse. Unzip those files in the workspace in your new laptop. This should do it.

Comment: I think this [link](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/migrating-from-eclipse-to-android-studio.html) will help you

Comment: I tried Prerak there is nothing there when I open anything in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to move the files to your new computer ;) then you have two possible approaches:

- Importing the Eclipse project directly into Studio (inside Studio, via File > Import Project, and then selecting the directory containing your Eclipse ADT project).
- Exporting the Eclipse project from Eclipse as a Gradle project (may need a recent version of Eclipse).

Check [this tutorial](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects) for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your project folder and pass it to your new computer. That's it. 
Eclipse keeps all project settings in a file inside the project folder.
However, you might need to change a few paths when starting the project on your new PC if you have been using absolute paths.

Comment: The new computer has android studio not eclipse

Comment: Haha, sorry I thought andriod studio was an eclipse plugin :)

Comment: I might be wrong but I have experienced that it is a bit of a hassle to handle Eclipse settings outside of eclipse. However I am sure there is a plugin for this somewhere.